# How do I generate an html file with ejs in command line?

Tags: node.js, ejs

I'm learning an [ejs tutorial](https://ejs.co/#install), which gives this command

```
ejs ./template_file.ejs -f data_file.json -o ./output.html
```

to generate an html file in command line.

Here is what I did on my ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

I created a directory

```
mkdir ejs-demo && cd "$_"
```

I initialized a new npm project

```
npm init -y
```

I installed the `ejs` package:

```
npm install ejs
```

I created a new file named `template_file.ejs`

```
nano template_file.ejs
```

I put the code from [another tutorial](https://ionicabizau.github.io/ejs-playground/) in `template_file.ejs`

```
OK, so have fun! :D
-------------------
<%
    var fruits = ["Apple", "Pear", "Orange", "Lemon"]
      , random = " ".repeat(2).split("").map(x => Math.random())
      ;
%>

These fruits are amazing:
<% for(var i = 0; i < fruits.length; ++i) {%>
  - <%=fruits[i]%>s<% } %>

Let's see some random numbers:

<% random.forEach((c, i) => {
%> <%=c.toFixed(10) + ((i + 1) % 6 === 0 ? "\n": "") %><%});%>
```

I saved and quit the editor.

I tried the following command

```
ejs ./template_file.ejs -o ./output.html
```

and got

> Command 'ejs' not found, did you mean
>
> …

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `ejs` executable is not in your $PATH but in `node_modules/.bin` directory and shell couldn't find it.

Use npm'x [exec command](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npx) to run binaries provided with packages:

```
npm exec -- ejs ./template_file.ejs -o ./output.html
```

Or with an alias:

```
npx ejs ./template_file.ejs -o ./output.html
```